# Athematic to to thematic raster

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a problem with the representation type of some rasters I'm trying to use for modeling. Some have a representation type of thematic, these work just fine, while others have an athematic representation type and do not work for modelling. I would like to convert the athematic rasters into thematic rasters so I can use them. The athematic rasters, for example, are rasters of oceanographic data such as temperature, salinity and currents, whereas the thematic ones (also oceanographic) are bathymetry and bottom roughness index. The datatype doesn't seem to make a difference, nor does it matter whether the data is continuous or not. The athematic rasters look normal and their data seems normal too, but somehow they are different. Here are images from the properties of both types of rasters, thematic and athematic.
[image]
[image]